# Error while installing APC

Tags: wordpress, caching, apc, apcu

I am getting following error while installing APC

I also followed the guidelines mentioned at https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/PHP#How_to_install_APC_module.3f but same error.

I am trying to install it in a Bitnami Image for Wordpress in Google App Engine.

```
         pecl install apc
        WARNING: configuration download directory "/tmp/pear/download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
        Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pecl.php.net" is not writeable by the current user
        user@edudrona-prod-vm:~$ sudo pecl install apc
        downloading APC-3.1.13.tgz ...
        Starting to download APC-3.1.13.tgz (171,591 bytes)
        .....................................done: 171,591 bytes
        55 source files, building
        running: phpize
        Configuring for:
        PHP Api Version:         20151012
        Zend Module Api No:      20151012
        Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
        Enable internal debugging in APC [no] :
        Enable per request file info about files used from the APC cache [no] :
        Enable spin locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] :
        Enable memory protection (EXPERIMENTAL) [no] :
        Enable pthread mutexes (default) [no] :
        Enable pthread read/write locks (EXPERIMENTAL) [yes] :
        building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJudBGM/APC-3.1.13
        running: /tmp/pear/temp/APC/configure --with-php-config=/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php-config --enable-apc-debug=no --enable-apc-filehits=no --enable-apc-spinlocks=no --enable-apc-memprotect=no --enable-apc-pthreadmutex=no --enable-apc-pthreadrwlocks=yes
        checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
        checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
        checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
        checking for cc... cc

        checking whether the C compiler works... yes
        checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
        checking for suffix of executables...
        checking whether we are cross compiling... no
        checking for suffix of object files... o
        checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes

        checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
        checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
        checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
        checking for icc... no
        checking for suncc... no
        checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
        checking for system library directory... lib
        checking if compiler supports -R... no
        checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
        checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
        checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
        checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
        checking for PHP prefix... /opt/bitnami/php
        checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/main -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/Zend -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/ext -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/ext/date/lib
        checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions
        checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/bitnami/php/include/php
        checking if debug is enabled... no
        checking if zts is enabled... no
        checking for re2c... re2c
        checking for re2c version... 0.13.5 (ok)
        checking for gawk... gawk
        checking whether to enable APC support... yes, shared
        checking whether we should enable cache request file info... no
        checking whether we should use mmap... yes
        checking whether we should use semaphore locking instead of fcntl... no
        checking whether we should use pthread mutex locking... no
        checking whether we should use pthread read/write locking... yes
        pthread rwlocks are supported!
        checking whether the target compiler supports builtin atomics... yes
        checking whether we should use spin locks... no
        checking whether we should enable memory protection... no
        checking for zend_set_lookup_function_hook... no
        checking for sigaction... yes
        checking for union semun... no
        checking whether we should enable valgrind support... checking for ANSI C header files... yes
        checking for sys/types.h... yes
        checking for sys/stat.h... yes
        checking for stdlib.h... yes
        checking for string.h... yes
        checking for memory.h... yes
        checking for strings.h... yes
        checking for inttypes.h... yes
        checking for stdint.h... yes
        checking for unistd.h... yes
        yes
        checking valgrind/memcheck.h usability... no
        checking valgrind/memcheck.h presence... no
        checking for valgrind/memcheck.h... no
        checking for shm_open in -lrt... yes
        checking whether to include code coverage symbols... no
        checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
        checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
        checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
        checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
        checking whether ln -s works... yes
        checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
        checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
        checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
        checking for dlfcn.h... yes
        checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
        checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
        checking for objdir... .libs
        checking for ar... ar
        checking for ranlib... ranlib
        checking for strip... strip
        checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
        checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
        checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
        checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
        checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
        checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
        checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
        checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
        checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
        checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
        checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
        checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
        checking whether to build static libraries... no

        creating libtool
        appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
        configure: creating ./config.status
        config.status: creating config.h
        running: make
        /bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJudBGM/APC-3.1.13/libtool --mode=compile cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJudBGM/APC-3.1.13/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJudBGM/APC-3.1.13/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/APC -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/main -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/Zend -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/ext -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I/opt/bitnami/common/include   -c /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c -o apc.lo
        mkdir .libs
         cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJudBGM/APC-3.1.13/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJudBGM/APC-3.1.13/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/APC -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/main -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/Zend -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/ext -I/opt/bitnami/php/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/opt/bitnami/common/include -c /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
        In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:38:0,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:43,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:40,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
        /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h: In function ‘apc_register_serializer’:
        /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:45:33: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘zend_get_constant’ from incompatible pointer type
         #define APC_SERIALIZER_CONSTANT "\000apc_register_serializer-" APC_SERIALIZER_ABI
                                         ^
        /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:64:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘APC_SERIALIZER_CONSTANT’
             if (zend_get_constant(APC_SERIALIZER_CONSTANT, sizeof(APC_SERIALIZER_CONSTANT)-1, &apc_magic_constant TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                   ^
        In file included from /opt/bitnami/php/include/php/main/php.h:396:0,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:61,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:34:
        /opt/bitnami/php/include/php/Zend/zend_constants.h:68:16: note: expected ‘struct zend_string *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
         ZEND_API zval *zend_get_constant(zend_string *name);
                        ^
        In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_main.h:38:0,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_compile.h:43,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:40,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:
        /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_serializer.h:64:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘zend_get_constant’
             if (zend_get_constant(APC_SERIALIZER_CONSTANT, sizeof(APC_SERIALIZER_CONSTANT)-1, &apc_magic_constant TSRMLS_CC)) {
                 ^
        In file included from /opt/bitnami/php/include/php/main/php.h:396:0,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.h:61,
                         from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:34:
        /opt/bitnami/php/include/php/Zend/zend_constants.h:68:16: note: declared here
         ZEND_API zval *zend_get_constant(zend_string *name);
                        ^
        In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:36:0:
        /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h: At top level:
        /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc_cache.h:136:9: error: unknown type name ‘zend_uint’
                 zend_uint *exec_refcount;   /* refcount member of zend_op_array refreshed before execution */
                 ^
        /tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:47:43: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
         #   include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"
                                                   ^
        compilation terminated.
        Makefile:195: recipe for target 'apc.lo' failed
        make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
        ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605999/how-can-i-find-php-smart-string-h-instead-of-php-smart-str-h