# how can I find php_smart_string.h instead of php_smart_str.h?

Tags: php

```
It's me:/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3# make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/include -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/main -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3 -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/inclued.c -o inclued.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/include -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/main -I/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3 -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/inclued.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/inclued.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/inclued.c:30:0:
/tmp/pear/install/inclued-0.1.3/php_inclued.h:29:40: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"
                                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [inclued.lo] Error 1
```

I was woking on install 'inclued' on php7, ubuntu 14.04.

After reading some articles,

I have a config.m4 to run 'phpize', and unzip the inclued-0.1.3.tgz

and, with this root, in command line,

I put './configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config'

(that's where php-config file was.)

and

make

and prints out 'php_smart_str.h' not found.

I knew that on php7, php_smart_str.h was renamed to php_smart_string.h.

And how can I to change to (I don't know what I do.) that?

I can find php_smart_string.h is in

'/usr/inclued/php/20151012/ext/standard', and maybe 'make' didn't know that.

How can I fix this problem?

On php-config,

```
SED="/bin/sed"
prefix="/usr"
datarootdir="/usr/share"
exec_prefix="${prefix}"
version="7.0.14-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1"
vernum="70014"
include_dir="${prefix}/include/php/20151012"
includes="-I$include_dir -I$include_dir/main -I$include_dir/TSRM -I$include_dir/Zend -I$include_dir/ext -I$include_dir/ext/date/lib $(getconf LFS_CFLAGS)"
ldflags="-L$prefix/lib/php/20151012  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
libs="-lcrypt   -lresolv -lcrypt -lz -lpcre -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lcrypt "
extension_dir="${prefix}/lib/php/20151012"
man_dir=`eval echo /usr/share/man`
program_prefix=""
program_suffix="7.0"
exe_extension=""
php_cli_binary=NONE
php_cgi_binary=NONE
```

like this.

Comment: As I found, it is because of non-supported php7 of inclued package. If any infomations, please leave it for those who've been difficulty of installing old packages.

Answer (score 1):

in line 40 of memcache.c:

```
#include "ext/standard/php_var.h"
#include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"  <--- this one
#include "php_network.h"


#include "ext/standard/php_var.h"
#include "ext/standard/php_smart_string.h" <--- add "ing" and magic goes live
#include "php_network.h"
```